# How to add symfony 2 Master security to complete project

Tags: symfony

I have developed a symfony application. It is on deployment stage. Client asked me to set A master security to complete project until testing not completed. Actually He want to make it private until launch site. Can some body help me about this how can I do this.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Your question is not clear? Unless you re-word it, I don't think you will get much help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make symfony project password protected during testing and development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858904/how-to-make-symfony-project-password-protected-during-testing-and-development)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this basic authentication for your use case http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate